# Parse.com schedule a recurring push

Tags: parse-platform

is it possible, through Parse.com, to schedule a push notification to be sent out every day at a certain (local) time? I have figured out how to schedule pushes in local time, but not how to have them happen every day.

Comment: Nope  You have to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule a [background job](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced-background-jobs) to run at a recurring time and programmatically trigger the push within it.

```
Parse.Cloud.job('sendRecurringNotification', function(request, response) {        
    Parse.Push.send({
        channels: ['a-reminder'],
        data: {
          alert: 'The kitchen is closing in 25 minutes'
        }
     }, {
        success: function() {
          response.success('scheduled order reminder notification')
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error('unable to schedule order reminder notification with error ' + error)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: how do I schedule it to run at a local time? Thanks!